# Error in Vb program

Tags: vb.net

Program for method overloading
 class book

```
Public Class clsBook
    Public Function show(ByVal bn As Integer)
        MsgBox(bn)
    End Function
    Public Function show(ByVal bn As Integer, ByVal bna As String)
        MsgBox(bn, bna)
    End Function
    Public Function show(ByVal bn As Integer, ByVal bna As String, ByVal bp As String)
        MsgBox(bn, bna, bp)
    End Function
End Class
```

on Button_Event

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim obj As New clsBook
        obj.show(5)
        obj.show(5, "JAVA")
        obj.show(5, "JAVA", "XYZ")
    End Sub
```

Error=

```
Conversion from string "JAVA" to type 'Integer' is not valid.
```

Could anyone please explain how to go about fixing this?

Comment: Read the documentation for MsgBox  :)

Comment: It would be difficult to find a more complete example of poor naming than this code...

Comment: You should try debugging/stepping through your code to see. But pretty much, the string 'JAVA' is not an int

Comment: The second parameter in [`MsgBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx) is a `MsgBoxStyle` which is an enum. Therefore you get the exception because `"JAVA"` cannot be casted to an `Integer`. I would set `Option Strict` to `On`, then it would not even compile (what is better).

Comment: In Function show i have declared the second argument as string than why there is type conversion error .

Comment: @user3396184: the error is not in `obj.show(5, "JAVA")` but in `MsgBox(bn, bna)`. Read my comment before yours.

Comment: still giggleing to myself over that classy naming :P

Comment: I got the silly mistake .Sorry for disturbing

Answer (score 1):

do you want to concatenate all arguments in show() into a single msgbox?

if yes, it should be like this:

```
Public Class clsBook
    Public Function show(ByVal bn As Integer)
        MsgBox(bn)
    End Function
    Public Function show(ByVal bn As Integer, ByVal bna As String)
        MsgBox(bn & " " & bna)
    End Function
    Public Function show(ByVal bn As Integer, ByVal bna As String, ByVal bp As String)
        MsgBox(bn & " " & bna & " " & bp)
    End Function
End Class
```

but if you want to show every arguments in a separate msgbox:

```
Public Class clsBook
        Public Function show(ByVal bn As Integer)
            MsgBox(bn)
        End Function
        Public Function show(ByVal bn As Integer, ByVal bna As String)
            MsgBox(bn)
            MsgBox(bna)
        End Function
        Public Function show(ByVal bn As Integer, ByVal bna As String, ByVal bp As String)
            MsgBox(bn)
            MsgBox(bna)
            MsgBox(bp)
        End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [*MicroSoft's*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/139z2azd(v=vs.90).aspx) Explanation the second Parameter in the `MsgBox()` function is **Buttons :**
It is optional, Numeric expression that is the sum of values specifying *the number and type of buttons to display*, the **icon style to use**, the identity of the default button, and the modality of the message box.

**Syntax for MsgBox() is :**

```
Public Function MsgBox( _
   ByVal Prompt As Object, _
   Optional ByVal Buttons As MsgBoxStyle = MsgBoxStyle.OKOnly, _
   Optional ByVal Title As Object = Nothing _
) As MsgBoxResult
```

hence when you call the function as `MsgBox(bn, bna)` then the second parameter must be an integer value but you are giving `"JAVA"` which gives error.

To full fill your task you need to change it as:

```
MsgBox(bn & "," & bna)
```